# Fetch from API and put into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

So I'm trying to take an object from an API and push that into an array. I put it into a loop so that it will do it multiple times base on a number.

```
function arrayAPI(){
    console.log("arrayAPI ran");

    let dogPool = [];
    for (i=0; i<dogNumber; i++){
        fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(response => responseJSON)
        .then(responseJSON => dogPool.push(responseJSON))
        .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));
    }

    console.log(dogPool);

    createTable(dogPool);
```

However there is something wrong with my fetch code. It goes straight to the `.catch`. If I loop it, it will play the error message each time also.

The `console.log(dogPool)` tells me that the array is empty.

Comment: See the referenced question for why `dogPool` is empty. For the rest: your code does not make sense. `response => respnseJSON`: what is `respnseJSON`? That is an undeclared variable? You should do `=> response.json()` to get the JSON from the response. See the examples in [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) documentation.

Comment: ```
 let dogPool = [];
    for (i=0; i<dogNumber; i++){
        fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => dogPool.push(responseJSON))
        .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));
    }
```
Ya, thanks. This works a lot better. no error.